# How delegate events in Internet Explorer 8 and 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following divs:

```
<div class="test0 clickable">
   <div class="test1 clickable">
      <div class="test2 clickable">Click me</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I click in "test2" I want that div test2 is removed from the dom and after that div test1. It works on all major browsers except for IE8 and IE9.

The JavaScript is:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(event){ 
  //if (some event condition)
     $(this).remove();
});
```

How can I guarantee that the click event is bubbling from test2 to test1 such that both divs are removed based on a condition of the "event" object?

Comment: So in IE `test1` is not removed?

Comment: Might be another case of IE not following the standard event model…

Comment: Note, it works in IE9, but not IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/Ttn8g/4/ (make sure console is open)

Comment: Yes test1 is not removed in IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly removing the parent, if it matches the selector :

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){ 
    $(this).remove();
    if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('clickable') ) $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Or `$(this).parents(".clickable").remove()` since all parents that are .clickable will eventually be bubbled to assuming nothing stops it on the way.

Comment: I updated my post. The removal of a div should be based on some event conditions, e.g., based on mouse position. So I need that each clickable receives the event object from the click event.

Comment: Does the mouse position change from element to element ?

Comment: No the mouse position does not change, but based on the position I will decide if the div should be closed.

Comment: @adeneo what if there are more that one clickable items above? Is there a way to make this recursively working. I mean, can the event from the first click be bubbled up to the last ".clickable" element in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Use stopPropagation

```
$(".clickable").click(function(event){ 
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what he wants?

Comment: he want to delete the child first and to the parents rt..?

Comment: That's what he wrote: _guarantee that ... both divs are removed_

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IE has some problems with implementing the [standardized event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow). However, by deferring the node removal this should be easy to work around:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(event){
    var toremove = this;
    if (/*some event condition*/)
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(toremove).remove();
        }, 0);
});
```